# Grub Theme - how to specificy the font properly

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, fonts

I want to adjust a grub theme to have a truly large font (about double from what is normal). I usually work with the `install.sh` that comes with it and with [`grub-customizer`](https://itsfoss.com/grub-customizer-ubuntu/).

The easy part, consensus everywhere:
Take a (vector, i.e. ttf) font, and convert it to the (pixel, `.pf2`) font, placed in `/boot/grub/fonts/`:

```
sudo grub-mkfont --output=/boot/grub/fonts/DejaVuSansMono36.pf2 \
    --size=36 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
```

*The tough or strange part:* Specifying this font in the central theme's settings file is not working. Somehow a space separated formed is required?!?

```
title-font: "Sans Regular 12"
or
title-font: "Gnu Unifont Mono Regular 16"
or
terminal-font: "Lato 12"
```

#### Questions:

- **How do I get from above literal filename `DejaVuSansMono36.pf2` to the "pretty name"?** (guessing the right spots for spaces?)
- **And how does the referencing work?**
- **And, should I put the .pf2 in the final place, or place it in theme folder?** ([looking at github](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Agithub.com+grub+themes.txt), the latter seems right...)

The [**grub theme spec**](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Theme-file-format.html) does not says **anything** about this `<longname><space><size>` format. Given that `.pf2` are hardcoded pixel-fonts (like in the 90's :-) I wonder what value a size indication is anyway...

---

**small addition**

The pretty, “spacy” name can be found out by virtue of hex editor:
Still a bit of a wonder, how it gets referenced. Does grub (or grub customizer) parse all existing `*.pf2` files for the prettier name *contained* ?!? (or is there a lookup-table somewhere I… overlooked?)

[image]